# unrecognized selector sent to instance AdViewController

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, xcode4.5

I have a problem when i built mi project of xcode-unity to ios, it crash!!!, i looking for the internet and i dont find nothing that fix my problem, i tried to all.

in console:

> 2013-01-24 11:50:05.013 pruebas[1912:907] -[AdViewController
>   accelerometer:didAccelerate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1e0ac600 2013-01-24 11:50:05.015 pruebas[1912:907] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[AdViewController accelerometer:didAccelerate:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1e0ac600'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x38e002a3 0x330e797f 0x38e03e07 0x38e02531 0x38d59f68 0xc8a668 0x3a730717 0x3a4c1351 0x3a4c06cd
>   0x3a4c011b 0x372f85a3 0x372f81d3 0x38dd5173 0x38dd5117 0x38dd3f99
>   0x38d46ebd 0x38d46d49 0x372f72eb 0x3a5142f9 0xfe9b8 0xf9898)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

and when i stop the project, the exception redirect me to main.mm file in the line:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");
```

i dont know what happen, at the first time, dont have this problem but when upgrade xcode to 4.5.2 version, the exception is appear

i hope you understand me and can help me

thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is deprecated in iOS5. You must build your project to target iOS 5 or earlier.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

You must replace it with Core Motion functionality to move to a newer version of iOS.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009670

Comment: hi thanks for your answered, and which is the method equivalent in ios 6?? i am beginner in objective-c

Comment: thank you!!! and now to programing :)